# Android - Accessing custom compound view's class from a List Adapter

Tags: java, android

I'm writing an android alarm application, and I'm having trouble gaining access to a class I created, which is a custom compound view.

So, I have

```
// Classes
public class AlarmListActivity extends ListActivity{...}
public class AlarmListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{...}

// My custom compound view class, basically 2 labels and a toggle button
// with an onClickListener outside the toggle button also
public class ToggleMenu extends RelativeLayout{...}

// XML
// The XML layout for AlarmListActivity
activity_alarm_list.xml
// The XML layout for ToggleMenu
toggle_menu.xml
```

The ToggleMenu works fine in other places, but in the AlarmListAdapter, I get an error when I try to convert the inflated view to a ToggleMenu.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toggle_menu, parent, true);
    }

    view = (ToggleMenu)view;

    <...>

    return view
}
```

I have tried switch the boolean in inflate(), and it will give me a different error depending on the value.
false is a 'cannot convert RelativeLayout to ToggleMenu error', which I believe is due to the fact that RelativeLayout is the root element in toggle_menu.xml.

So I researched and found that true might be what I need, but I get an error of
'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView'.

Am I trying to access the ToggleMenu class in the adapter's getView() incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this a while back, and thought I would post the answer in case some one stumbled on it with the same problem.

I was trying to inflate the compound layout I made for the ToggleMenu, when I should have been inflating an xml file containing only a  view.

I created an xml file containing only that, named alarm_list_item, and I switched

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toggle_menu, parent, true);
```

to

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_item, parent, true);
```

and the problem was solved.